# Trouble finding next threshold in IDA* algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I'm working with 3x3 and 4x4 sliding puzzle and I did my A* algorithm and works as expected. But now I have to code the IDA* since 4x4 is a big big deal. I'm having trouble finding the next threshold in each iteration of the recursive thing.

Taken from Korf's:
*"At each iteration, the
threshold used for the next iteration is the minimum cost of all values that
exceeded the current threshold."*

This is the part that I just can't code, I understand it but just can't.

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IDAstar.h"
using namespace std;

void IDAstar::DFS(state &start, state &goal, int d, int &f, bool &foundGoal, int Puzzle){
    if(start == goal){
        cout << "Cost: " << start.cost << endl;
        foundGoal = true;
        return;
    }
    vector<Action> PossibleActions;
    environment.GetActions(start, PossibleActions, Puzzle);
    for(int i=0;i<PossibleActions.size();i++){
            /*The missing code should
                go around here?*/
        state simulator;                               
        simulator = start;
        environment.ApplyAction(simulator, PossibleActions[i], Puzzle);
        simulator.cost = simulator.cost + 1;
        simulador.heuristic = environment.HCost(simulator, Puzzle);
        if(simulator.cost+simulator.heuristic <= d)
                    /* or inside this if? */
            DFS(start, environment.goal, d, f, foundGoal, Puzzle);
    }
}

void IDAstar::GetPath(state &start, int Puzzle){
    int d = environment.HCost(start, Puzzle);     
    int f = d; 
    environment.SetGoal(Puzzle);
    bool foundGoal = false;    
    while(true){    
        DFS(start, environment.goal, d, f, foundGoal, Puzzle);
        d = f;
        if(foundGoal)
            return;
    }
}
```

So a few explanations:

- d is the variable that defines the depth of the search at each
  iteration
- f is the variable I created to receive the minimum ... (What I said
  about Korf's that I can't code)
- environment, Action and state are classes that I created to help to
  solve the problem
- Puzzle is an int (9 or 16) to represent which puzzle I'm dealing
  with.

Please any help would be much appreciated!

If you need any other cpp file - like Action/environment classes - or .h file just ask.

Comment: Looking at the explanation on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*), it seems that `d` works as a cutoff for the current search recursion, and once that recursion has completed, if no solution has been found, we raise the cut off to the minimum cost calculated during that last `DFS`, and search again. This is basically what you do in `GetPath`. In `DFS`, if the cost for the current call is already above `d`, you stop there, and return that value. Otherwise, you iteratively recurse and keep the minimum returned value.